# What is an example of JSF "No Query Data" short-circuit from Restore View to Render Response

Tags: jsf-2

Core JavaServer Faces Third Edition mentions a case where JSF can go from the Restore View phase directly to the Render Response Phase. What is a real-world example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will happen when there's no means of a postback request (i.e. it's a plain GET request) and the targeted view doesn't contain any view parameters (i.e. there are no `<f:viewParam>` tags in the view). There's then simply nothing to process on apply request values phase (collect request parameters), validations phase (convert/validate them), update model values phase (set bean properties) and invoke action phase (invoke bean action method). JSF will then just bypass all those phases.

The real world exampe is, well, just a plain GET request without view params like as when you open the page directly by following a link or bookmark or by entering its URL in browser address bar, where the targeted view doesn't have any `<f:viewParam>`.